# How to determine interventional distributions from observational data?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, causality

How do we compute/query interventional distributions from observational data (i.e. without knowledge of the causal graph such as a Structural Causal Model (SCM))?

Comment: Well, if you don't have a causal graph and you don't have any SCMs, you're limited to the Potential Outcomes Framework, but even that is based fundamentally on SCMs. My advice: try to get a causal graph for your problem, either through some of the algorithms that can at least get the skeleton right, or through a subject matter expert (SME), or whatever.

Comment: @AdrianKeister How would I compute/query interventional distribution with Potential Outcomes Framework? My understanding was that Potential Outcomes Framework is based on the idea of counterfactuals; and not interventions. I appreciate your clarification, explaining how the Potential Outcomes Framework can be leveraged to determine an interventional query. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that question, because I haven't studied the Potential Outcomes Framework. All my causal study so far has been with Pearl's DAG framework. I do have the seminal book on PO, but I haven't started it, yet, as I don't have all the prerequisites under my belt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, observational data is not sufficient to obtain the interventional distributions. You will "only" obtain the [Markov equivalence class](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/manudb/autoreg/reviewer/gE1hWOyKD1tUGHmzxYFi/getfile2/6419/manuscript/JMLR-14-396-1.pdf) (e.g. with the `pcalg` [R-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcalg/index.html)). E.g., think of two random variables $A$ and $B$, where your observation consists only of an $n\times 2$ table of $n$ observations of the pairs $(a_i, b_i)$. This table can only tell you (approximately) whether they are dependent or not. It doesn't contain any information about whether $A$ causes $B$, i.e. $A\to B$, or $B$ causes $A$, i.e. $A\leftarrow B$.

However, those equivalence classes are often not too large (see [the linked paper above](https://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/manudb/autoreg/reviewer/gE1hWOyKD1tUGHmzxYFi/getfile2/6419/manuscript/JMLR-14-396-1.pdf) and [this paper, section 3](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-statistics-031017-100053)), so this can already contain lots of helpful information.

The standard methods of getting (some of) the interventional distributions via adjustment sets (e.g. the [backdoor method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_model#Confounder/deconfounder)) all presume some extra knowledge such as that the treatment does cause the outcome and the knowledge of all the confounders. But that information is often available, at least approximately.

Another approach is that of [additive noise models](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2008/file/f7664060cc52bc6f3d620bcedc94a4b6-Paper.pdf): it often suffices to have only a little bit of qualitative information about the distributions to be able to identify the causal model and the interventional distributions.

Finally, also addressing the comments to the question, note that there is nothing that the method of potential outcomes can do that Pearl's causal graph approach cannot, and vice versa. It is just that some tasks are sometimes easier to tackle with one method than with the other; it is also often a question of subjective taste. For instance, the backdoor method is part of both approaches, and both deal with counterfactuals, too.